# WSO2 Data Analytics Server - Analytics Dashboard view function not responding to any browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, wso2, wso2-das

I'm using updated versions of Chrome & Fire fox web browsers.Analytics Dashboard(WSO2DAS)is not working(view) in any case.do we need install any plugins?Both browsers are not responding.

```
      Google Chrome - Version 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit)
      Firefox       - 47.0 
      OS            - ubuntu
```

for more details : https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Analyzing+Smart+Home+Data

Comment: No you do not need any extra plugins, but You need Javascript enabled in your browser. Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: what is the url used ? https://<HOST_NAME>:<PORT>/portal/dashboards?

Answer (score 1):

The issue occured when I accessed the dashboard via the IP and was able to view when I viewed using localhost.

If you have already published data for the sample shut down the server and please follow the below steps

step1: generate a self signed certificate for your IP address(10.100.0.xx)
keytool -genkey -alias das -keyalg RSA -keystore  das.jks -keysize 2048

```
 What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  10.100.0.xx
```

step2:Take a back-up of the current /repository/resources/security/ directory.

step3: import your certificate into wso2carbon.jks.
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore das.jks -destkeystore wso2carbon.jks -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype jks -srcstorepass wso2carbon -deststorepass wso2carbon

step4:Since we can't have two different private keys, lets delete the previous one.
keytool -delete -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -storepass wso2carbon

step5: export the public key :keytool -export -keystore das.jks -alias das -file test.cer

step6 :import the public cert to client-truststore.jks
keytool -import -alias das -file test.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks

step7: update the repository/conf/carbon.xml

```
 <KeyStore>
        <!-- Keystore file location-->
        <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
        <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
        <Type>JKS</Type>
        <!-- Keystore password-->
        <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
        <!-- Private Key alias-->
        <KeyAlias>das</KeyAlias>
        <!-- Private Key password-->
        <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
    </KeyStore>
```

step8: update the   "identityAlias": "das", in designer.json  within the path wso2das-3.0.1/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/configs/designer.json

more details can be found in http://udarakr.blogspot.com/2014/04/you-may-get-following-error-and-your.html